# Website works fine on local server but fails in GitHub pages

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I have a Jekyll website that also uses paginate-v2. I was deploying it on GitHub pages, and it was working fine, until I added pagination.

You can get the code on https://github.com/divyessh/tennis-events/

And here is the last deployment without pagination:

https://divyessh.github.io/tennis-events/

Answer (score 2):

Paginate-V2 is not listed as [supported by Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/versions/), and is likely not supported. However judging by your use case you should be able to use the supported version of [Paginate](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-paginate).

Comment: Thanks joeyy, will try to replace the jekyll package tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe github pages uses a custom ruby version. If you get that information, docker could help you to replicate the exact github pages infrastructure in your localhost.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, can you please attach a link or tutorial of how I can do that.

Comment: Also, I just checked, I use ruby 2.7.0 in my system, and github pages use 2.7.3. I dont think it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if running adding `webrick` gem to your project resolves the GitHub pages build error.

Here are the following steps I did to make your website work locally using `jekyll serve`.

1. Cloned git [repo](https://github.com/divyessh/tennis-events/) at commit [425bb79b99deb4b7a00d2a13b4fd8c857a22ca49](https://github.com/Divyessh/tennis-events/commit/425bb79b99deb4b7a00d2a13b4fd8c857a22ca49).
2. `bundle install` in `tennis-events` directory
3. `bundle exec jekyll serve`
4. Observed this error `` /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError) ``
5. Found this jekyll issue [#8523](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523)
6. Ran `bundle add webrick` per [issue#8523 comment](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523#issuecomment-751409319)
7. `bundle exec jekyll serve`
8. Observed website rendering at http://localhost:4000/tennis-events/
   [image: jekyll serve screenshot]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, but I followed these steps and still the github pages is failing. 
[commit](https://github.com/Divyessh/tennis-events/commit/616a78e437097b86e5db0f6442f702c9d60d2cd5) Here you can see I addedthe webrick, but it still fialed.

Comment: @Divyessh Since GitHub Pages reports only "Page build failed.", it makes it difficult to know what error is keeping the build from being successful.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue after some research
I have a solution if GitHub pages do not support Paginate-V2, if you want to use that then you need to integrate with the third-party cms like I am using site leaf which will allows you to utilize the functionality in v2

https://github.com/DevlopersField/jekyll-paginate-v2

for more https://learn.siteleaf.com/themes/jekyll-plugins/